# Ajax and voting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have a parent class Car and the `/cars/show` page lists all of the reviews associated with it. The reviews can be voted on. I am having some difficulty getting the `:votes_count` to update by JavaScript.

#### /votes/create.js.erb

```
$("#votes").html("<%= review.votes_count %>")  // this does not work
```

#### /cars/show

```
<% @car.reviews.each do |review| %>
  <p id='votes'><%= pluralize(review.votes_count, 'vote') %></p>

  <% if current_user  %>
    <%= form_for(@vote, :remote => true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field "review_id", :value => review.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field "user_id",   :value => current_user.id %>
      <%= f.submit "vote" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <br />
  <%= review.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, and? Are you seeing an error in the JavaScript console? Have you checked to see what `$("#votes")` returns? Have you checked to see if the generated markup is what you expect it to be? Try more things, then tell us what worked, what didn't, and most importantly *in what way*.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `review' from the create.js.erb file.  What makes this a little more complicated than usual is the fact that I have to loop through the reviews that match @car.  Will I need to do this again somehow to change just one :votes_count attribute?

Comment: Looks like `review` isn't being assigned when `create.js.erb` is being rendered. Figure out why.

A secondary issue I just noticed is that you're doing `<p id='votes'>` inside a loop. But every id on the page must be unique (this is required by the HTML spec). You should be using a class instead.

Comment: (And as a side note, a more Rails-y way to do this would be to use a partial for the `@car.reviews` collection rather than using an `each` loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create.js.erb

```
    <% @car.reviews.each do |review| %>
    $("#review_<%= review.id %>").html("<%= pluralize(review.votes_count, 'vote') %>");
    <% end %>
```